# Ultrafilter base: $A\cup B\in\mathfrak{M}\implies (A\in \mathfrak{M}\,\lor\, B\in\mathfrak{M})$

Tags: general-topology, filters

I'm going through James Dugundji's *Topology* [$\star$] but I'm having trouble with Chapter X, Section 7, Problem 1:

> Let $\mathfrak{M}$ be a maximal filterbase [ultrafilter base] in $Y$, and let $A,\, B\subseteq Y$ be such that $A\cup B\in\mathfrak{M}$. Prove: Either $A\in\mathfrak{M}$ or $B\in\mathfrak{M}$.

**Context.**
A *filterbase* is defined as a family of non-empty sets such that the intersection of any pair of elements of the family contains some other element of the family. A *maximal filterbase* (ultrafilter base) is defined as a filterbase $\mathfrak{M}$ such that for any filterbase $\mathfrak{A}$, $\mathfrak{A}\vdash\mathfrak{M}\implies \mathfrak{M}\vdash \mathfrak{A}$, where $\mathfrak{A}\vdash \mathfrak{B}$ iff for every $B\in\mathfrak{B}$, there is a $A\in\mathfrak{A}$ s.t. $A\subseteq B$. A handy characterisation of maximality is the following: A filterbase $\mathfrak{M}$ in a space $Y$ is maximal iff for any $A\subseteq Y$, one of the two sets, $A$, $\mathscr{C}A$, contains a member of $\mathfrak{M}$ ([$\star$], Chap X, 7.2).

**My attempt.**
Assume $A$ and $B$ both don't contain an element from $\mathfrak{M}$. Then $\mathscr{C}A$ and $\mathscr{C}B$ do. Let $M_\alpha, M_\beta\in\mathfrak{M}$ be s.t. $M_\alpha\subseteq \mathscr{C}A$ and $M_\beta\subseteq \mathscr{C}B$. Let $M_\gamma\subseteq M_\alpha\cap M_\beta\subseteq \mathscr{C}A\cap\mathscr{C}B=\mathscr{C}(A\cup B)$. Then $M_\gamma\cap (A\cup B)=\emptyset$, a contradiction (since $A\cup B\in\mathfrak{M}$). Therefore, either $A$ or $B$ contain an element of $\mathfrak{M}$.

This is as close as I've gotten. That is, I managed to prove that $A$ or $B$ contain an element of $\mathfrak{M}$ but not that $A$ or $B$ themselves belong to $\mathfrak{M}$. I'm looking for any hints on how to continue, if I was on the right track, or an alternative direction in which I can go.

Comment: Is $\{ \{0\}, \mathbb{R}\}$ a maximal filterbase in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring, is the problem flawed?

Comment: I can't say, as I've never seen nor dealt with "maximal filterbases," (though I didn't study in that field, so it doesn't mean much...) but $A\cup B \in \mathfrak{M} \implies A \in \mathfrak{M} \lor B \in \mathfrak{M}$ looks like we're talking about ultrafilters, not filter bases.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I have a very old copy of the text. I was looking through newer online versions of it and the problem differs: $A$ and $B$ are required to be disjoint. This still doesn't account for your counterexample; $\{\{0\},\mathbb{R}\}$ as a maximal filterbase in $\mathbb{R}$. I'll just assume the problem is flawed (as with other problems present in the text which, some, where corrected later). Thanks for preventing me form wasting any more time on it.